# JQuery UI Sortable: how to make a small area draggable, not the entire sortable element?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I using JQuery UI Sortable as follows. HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li><div class="drag-handle">drag me</div>Item 1</li>
  <li><div class="drag-handle">drag me</div>Item 2</li>
  <li><div class="drag-handle">drag me</div>Item 3</li>
  <li><div class="drag-handle">drag me</div>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  });
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    height: 90px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.drag-handle {
    background-color: yellow;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
}
```

At this moment, the whole `<li>` element is draggable. How can I make only div.drag-handle areas draggable with the same results (that is, moving `<li>` elements?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, use the [handle option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle).

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".drag-handle"
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a4Wr6/)